# Multi column verification, 1 column comparison

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets.  One is my spreadsheet that I use to project what my commissions should be each month for each sale, the other is from the company I contract for (an excel statement of what commissions they paid me).  I need to compare commissions from the company sheet to my own, to verify that I was paid correctly and for whom.  Since the spreadsheets are from two sources the setups are different, so, line by line they will not match up.
 The Spreadsheets could be 1000-2000 lines deep.

First issue, I need to look at the entire column for multiple columns to verify I am looking at the correct person.
Second Issue, need to then compare the commission amount of that person and output only if they don't match. 
On sheet one, the person might be found on line 523.
On sheet two, the person might be found on line 489

I need to verify from both sheets: separate columns: the last name, then the first name, then the effective date, if that is all correct on the same line, then compare the commission amount from two spreadsheets and output some response to indicate if the commission cells are different amounts.

I have been looking at IF/ELSE, ISERROR, VLOOKUP, but can't seem to find/figure out how to write the formula.
 At this point, I think it is a combination of all three, but I don't know how they can all work together.
For example, if the last name is Smith, I need it to them match up to William, then match up to the effective date of 1-1-19, then compare the commission.
Their could be several Smiths, also several Williams, but I would only have one William Smith with an effective date of 1-1-19.  So the formula must look down, but also stay on the same line once it's correctly matches up the first column, 2nd column, 3rd column to then compare the last one.

Please any ideas would be helpful.  I have watched lots of videos and researched, but can't find anything like what I'm doing.

worked on if/else, iserror, vlookup

result could should show the first and last names of commissions not matching

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54082552/edit) to give us sample data, expected outcome and what you've tried so far?

Comment: ^^^ What @cybernetic.nomad said - we need sample data. It's impossible to guess how your data is setup.

Comment: This is most likely what you need: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Comment: If you want something simple, create a helper column in both sheets where you join the 3 fields together, and use that for the lookup.